# Using Pybind with Bazel but setting Python Path?

Tags: python, bazel, pybind11

I am trying to use Pybind with Bazel, and I have been following the instructions on:
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11_bazel

It all works fine, and I was able to force it to use Python3 via the following command in my workspace:

```
python_configure(name = "local_config_python", python_version = "3")
```

However, the instructions are completely unclear on how to use it with a particular python say in a virtual env

This file here https://github.com/pybind/pybind11_bazel/blob/master/python_configure.bzl
says that we have to set two variables:

```
"""Repository rule for Python autoconfiguration.
`python_configure` depends on the following environment variables:
  * `PYTHON_BIN_PATH`: location of python binary.
  * `PYTHON_LIB_PATH`: Location of python libraries.
"""
```

I set them, but it doesnt actually respect these values. How can I actually pass in these varialbes, perhaps in my `cc_library` command. Is there an API to set the Python path in my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add these two as action_env in .bazelrc:

```
build --action_env=PYTHON_BIN_PATH=xxx
build --action_env=PYTHON_LIB_PATH=xxx
```